# Some parts of my objects are invisible in camera view

Tags: rendering, camera

[image]I tried to change Clip start in the camera settings  but it doesn't seem to change anything.Those parts are not rendered.How can I solve this?

Edit:
I have adjusted Clip end so the objects become entirely visible,but now there are weird artefacts on the object
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRKPf.png):https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdNjN.png

Comment: Try to adjust clip end.

Comment: @FFeller:thank you,that was what I am looking for!But now I have another problem:some weird artefacts appear on the object of the scene,how to get rid of that?

Comment: That's look like a mesh issue. I would like to suggest you to delete that monkey and add that again.

Comment: @ANIRUDDHSINH JADEJA:I tried to delete the object and readd it but the artefacts are still there

Comment: Adjust the clip distance for the camera.

Comment: Probably these are huge sizes, why don't you decrease the scale of the meshes?

Comment: I have already decreased the scale of the objects but the problem is still there

Comment: The problem is solved when I reincrease the Clip start after adjusting Clip end